# Do we have to force all FFLIB classes with `with sharing` keywords to pass security review?

Tags: security-review, fflib, with-sharing

I'm using FFLIB classes in my managed package and i just wanted to know if i should mark FFLIB classes use in my package with `with sharing` keyword to follow security review requirements ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could mark them `inherited sharing`, which means "with" unless called from a "without" context.